# Inner Join select only two records from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a subject and a departments table, Each subject is associated with departments table. I am trying to select all subjects including departments name. The code bellow work perfect but show only two records. Any Help will be appreciated

```
//Select statement
$selects=$connection->query("SELECT
subjects.id
, subjects.name
, subjects.related_to
, subjects.related_to_sem
, departments.dept
FROM subjects
INNER JOIN departments
ON subjects.related_to = departments.dep_id");

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered bootstrap-datatable datatable">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Sub Id</th>
<th>Subject Name</th>
<th>Related to Department</th>
<th>Related to Semester</th>
<th>Actions</th>
</tr>
</thead>   
<tbody>
<?php
while($result=$select->fetch_assoc()) { 
?>
<tr>
  <td><?php echo $result['id']; ?></td>
  <td class="center"><?php echo $result['name']; ?></td>
  <td class="center"><?php echo $result['dept']; ?></td>
 <td class="center"><?php echo $result['related_to_sem']; ?></td>
 <td class="center">
 <a class="btn btn-info" href="#">
<i class="icon-edit icon-white"></i>  
Edit                                            
</a>
<a class="btn btn-danger" href="#">
<i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i> 
Delete
</a>
</td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Change `inner` to `left` if you want to show all subjects with or without associated with department

Comment: If there are only two records in the dependant table that have foreign keys into the primary table then you will only get two rows back.  You need to check the validity of your data.  Also you might want to look into using a foreign key constraint on the dependant table (if you're using innoDB) to prevent records in the dependant table pointing to non-existent records in the primary table.

Comment: why inner join is not showing all records? any suggestion

Comment: Hello Mr  GordonM. There are two departments for now but each department have many subjects may be 20 plus so what i am trying to do is view all subjects and there related department name

Answer (score 0):

```
select 

subjects.id,subjects.name,
subjects.related_to,
subjects.related_to_sem,
departments.dept 

from 

subjects

LEFT OUTER JOIN departments ON subjects.id=departments.dep_id
```

Comment: thank you but using this i wont be able to select department name in my view.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following. I think you may have used the wrong fields in the join condition:

```
SELECT
      subjects.id
    , subjects.name
    , subjects.related_to
    , subjects.related_to_sem
    , departments.dept
FROM subjects
      INNER JOIN departments
                  /* ON subjects.id = departments.dep_id */
                  ON subjects.dep_id = departments.id
```

A "foreign key" in the subjects table for department is much more likely to be subjects.dep_id

Comment: no problem, it is helpful for all concerned to Tick the answer, this indicates to other readers what the answer is(was)